# How I can the code work when my table finishes in any column?

Tags: excel, vba

The code is working only if my table finishes on column AJ.

My table can finish before column AJ.

How I can amend the code so it works when my table finishes in any column?

```vb
Dim row As Long, Column As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    LastRow0 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).row
    For row = 8 To LastRow0 Step 3
        For Column = 5 To 35
            If Cells(row, Column).Value = "" Then
                Cells(row, Column).Value = 0
            End If
        Next Column
    Next row
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found the lastRow, now you need the lastColumn.

```
Dim row As Long, Column As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    LastRow0 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).row
    .UsedRange
    LastCol0 = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    For row = 8 To LastRow0 Step 3
        For Column = 5 To LastCol0
            If Cells(row, Column).Value = "" Then
                Cells(row, Column).Value = 0
            End If
        Next Column
    Next row
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! Much appreciated! . that was so obvious but yet hard for me at the same time. I am still learning :/

Comment: Glad I could help.